# Docker Maven Spotify plugin - Possible to switch to non-secure registry

Tags: maven, docker, maven-plugin, spotify, docker-registry

I'm using the [Spotify Maven plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.spotify/docker-maven-plugin) to automate the building and deploying of docker images when executing certain maven goals.

However, I'm running a private unsecured registry that is accessible through the following host: server.mydomain.com:5000. However, I can't seem to stop the plugin from forcing a secure push to the repository? It uses https://server.mydomain.com:5000.

Is there any way to force the plugin to not use https?

Thanks.

Edit:

Current plugin POM configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <imageName>server.mydomain.com:5000/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
        <baseImage>java</baseImage>
        <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}-packaged.jar"]</entryPoint>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                <include>${project.build.finalName}-packaged.jar</include>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <imageTags>
            <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
            <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
        </imageTags>
        <retryPushCount>0</retryPushCount>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-image</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>push-image</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>push</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the exception you're getting.

Comment: I think this issue matches the described behaviour: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/183 Will have to wait to get it addressed!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be Docker behavior and not related to the maven plugin you are using, see [this Docker issue](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/936) that mentions needing to set `--insecure-registry http://server.mydomain.com:5000` when starting the Docker daemon.

Comment: This is an issue with the plugin itself I believe... The Docker daemon is setup correctly with the insecure-registry option set. However, when the push-image goal is executed, the plugin attempts to push to https:// (not http)

Comment: Same issue here, I'm having `com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?` I have already removed the `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` from my environment and added the insecure registry flag to the engine. Could it be a bug of the plugin?